# Joining the IDF - Learning Hebrew required?

Tags: immigration, language, israel

I'm a foreigner who wishes to volunteer for the Israel Defence Forces. Am I required to learn Hebrew? Are there no English speaking commanders there?

Comment: What units in idf can I join by hebrew level 5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The IDF is using Hebrew, and even in the units with a significant Arab/Bedouin majority everyone will be speaking Hebrew on duty. But if you don't know the language - [they'll teach you](http://www.mahal-idf-volunteers.org/information/program.htm).

Answer (score -1):

With all due respect - the fact that you do not know the IDF well enough to realize it only uses Hebrew is a sign to wait before trying to volunteer. Not only is it possible that you simply won't be able too (there's isn't an equivalent of the French "Foreign Legion"); you might not yet realize what you might do there are more importantly, for exactly which purposes.